# ¿Como convertir un número decimal de base 10 a número flotante en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente lista de números:
1101004800
1106247680
1106247680
1112014848

Dichos números corresponden a los valores 20,30,40 y 50.

Lo que requiero es convertirlos a números enteros o flotantes, logre encontrar la forma de hacerlo en C++ utilizando el siguiente codigo:

```
    int n = 1101004800;
    int n2 = 1106247680;

    printf("%f\n", *((float*)&n));
    printf("%f\n", *((float*)&n2));
```

Pero necesito hacerlo en C# y no encontre la manera de hacerlo, alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Trate de usar la función Convert, en byte,Char,Double,int64,int32, ademas trate de utilizar string hexadecimal = 1101004800.ToString("X"); para convertirlo a hexadecimal y luego pasarlo a otro dato, pero no lo logre, ademas de eso llevo varios días buscando en foros y lo mas cercano que encontre fue ese código de c++, que si funciona pero lo necesito para c#.

Comment: @MiguelAlvarado Coloque una respuesta que creo que resuelve tu problema, pruebala y dime si te funciona correctamente.

Comment: @EduardoReyes No me funciono, cuando trate de hacerlo y pasarlo a un textBox o en un MessageBox el valor que me da es 1.106248E+09, estaba revisando y en donde saque el código de C++ que es en esta página https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488641/how-do-the-digits-1101004800-correspond-with-the-number-20, hay un comentario que dice “1101004800 decimal is 0x41A00000 hex, which is the IEEE-754 representation of 20.0. 1101529088 decimal is 0x41A80000 hex, which is the IEEE-754 representation of 21.0” creo que ahí está la respuesta, pero no entiendo como lograron convertirlo de hexadecimal.

Comment: El valor 1.106248E+09 es un `string` que el sistema convierte de `float` a `string`  de forma implicita, y lo muestra en fomato de notación cientifica, si no lanzó una excepción en tiempo de ejecución al realizar la conversión, entonces funcionó, convirtió el valor de `int` a `float` pero si despues lo pasas como argumento de tipo `string` veras un `string`, el sistema no necesita que especifiques la conversión a `string` por que se realiza de forma implicita, no sucede así para convertir de `int` a `float`, esta conversión es explicita, requiere que escribas una linea de código para ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre encontrar la forma de conseguirlo, la comparto por si alguien tiene el mismo problema:

```
        //Declarar variable como int
        int n = 1101004800;                  
        
        //Convertirla a byte
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(n);

        //Convertirla a float
        float flotante = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);

        //Mostrar en pantalla
        MessageBox.Show(flotante.ToString());
```

Esto da una salida de 20.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias opciones, a continuación te coloco dos,para cada valor`n` y `n2`.

```
  int n = 1101004800;
  int n2 = 1106247680;

  float fln = (float)n;
  float fln1 = System.Convert.ToSingle(n);
    
  float fln2 = (float)n2;
  float fln21 = System.Convert.ToSingle(n2);
```